# New laptop screen issue

Tags: lenovo-laptop

Hi I just installed my new laptop screen I made sure the cable is connected good I replaced screens before but this is the first time I encounter a problem like this Anyone can explain this, Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Please edit the title to get a summary of your problem.

Comment: What should I make the title I don't know the problem so I just put issue

Answer (score 0):

Probably you didn't install polarizing film:
[image: Monitor without polarizer. Image from google https://image.dhgate.com/albu_338725871_00/1.0x0.jpg]

Comment: There wasn't any that came with the screen.

Comment: Polarizing films are permanently glued on LCD displays.

Comment: Yea I bought my LCD screen from amazon.

Comment: according to [explanation of screen issues](https://www.laptopscreen.com/English/section/Articles/1245259090/Quick%20fix%20tips%20for%20simple%20screen%20issues/)
you can get white screen if backlight is working but there is no video signal... check that you connected flex correctly (it is fully inside)